# Implementing an Interface from another team

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface

I have received an api and some code snippets from another team. I am not sure how to get the ApiTest working. The first two snippets were provided to me. That last one is my attempt to implement the interface and get it working...

```
using com.XXXX.api;
class ApiTest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MicrositesApiFactory factory = MicrositesApiFactory.getInstance();
        Logger logger = factory.getLogger("ApiTest", typeof(Program));
        logger.error("created logger");

    /*  
    if (logger.isTraceEnabled)
    {
        logger.trace("acquired logger successfully");
    }
    */
        DatabaseMgr databaseMgr = factory.getDatabaseMgr("microsites");
    if (databaseMgr == null)
    {
        //logger.alert("unable to retrieve DatabaseMgr object");
    }
    else
    {
        DbConnection conn = databaseMgr.getDbConnection(DatabaseSchema.ApplicationSchema);
    }
    Console.In.ReadLine();
}
```

For whatever reason, they have included {...} after the methods. I am not sure what I need to do here.
The Interface they provided:

```
namespace com.XXXX.api
{
    public class MicrositesApiFactory
    {
       public static MicrositesApiFactory getInstance() {...}
       public Logger getLogger(String msId, Type type) {...}
       public DatabaseMgr getDatabaseMgr(String msId) {...}
    }
    public abstract class Logger
    {
       public String MicrositeId { get; set; }
       public abstract void alert(String message);
    }
    public enum DatabaseSchema
    {
       ApplicationSchema,
       ConsumerSchema,
       ContentSchema
    }
    public abstract class DatabaseMgr
    {
       public String MicrositeId { get; set; }
       protected DatabaseMgr(String micrositeId) { ... }
       public abstract DbConnection
       getDbConnection(DatabaseSchema schema);
    }
}
```

Here are my adaptions to the Interface to get it working.
I am not sure what the best way to do this.
From what I understand about Interfaces, I need to implement all of the methods.
Any advice on implementing Interfaces would be welcome.

This error is the only one that remains:

> DatabaseMgr does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

```
using System;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace com.tsystems_mms.phi.microsites.api
{

    public class MicrositesApiFactory : Logger
    {

        public override DbConnection getDbConnection(DatabaseSchema message)
        {
            DbConnection test = new SqlConnection();
            return test;
        }


        public DatabaseMgr getDatabaseMgr(String msId)
        {
            DatabaseMgr test = new MicrositesApiFactory();
            return test;
        }

        public static MicrositesApiFactory getInstance() {
            return new MicrositesApiFactory();
        }

        public override void alert(string message) { }

        public override bool isErrorEnabled
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public Logger getLogger(String msId, Type type)
        {
            Logger test = new MicrositesApiFactory();
            return test;
        }

    }
    public abstract class Logger : DatabaseMgr
    {
        public new String MicrositeId { get; set; }
        public abstract void alert(String message);
        public abstract bool isErrorEnabled { get; }
    }
    public enum DatabaseSchema
    {
        ApplicationSchema,
        ConsumerSchema,
        ContentSchema
    }
    public abstract class DatabaseMgr
    {
        public String MicrositeId { get; set; }

        protected DatabaseMgr(String micrositeId)
        {
        }

        public abstract DbConnection getDbConnection(DatabaseSchema schema);
    }
}
```

Comment: Taking a guess here, but your problem may be this line: `DatabaseMgr test = new MicrositesApiFactory();` The number of arguments may need to be the same. One fix would be to create a no-arg constructor for `DatabaseMgr`. If I'm flat out wrong, I'll remove this comment. :)

Comment: Why does `Logger` extend `DatabaseMgr`? Are you supposed to implement `DatabaseMgr`, `Logger` etc. or do they already exist?

Comment: @DavidLeverett protected DatabaseMgr() { ... }

Comment: Looks like you work primarily with Java developers...

Comment: @Lee MicrositesApiFactory inherits from Logger and Logger inherits from DatabaseMgr.. The return types in MicrositesApiFactory require Logger and DatabaseMgr. I could of create a different class, however I just chose to use the existing MicrositesApiFactory class. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: @DrewKennedy what do you mean Drew??

Comment: @RonBeyer What makes you think they are primarily java developers?

Comment: Almost all Java api's namespaces begin with "com.something.somethingelse", and usually in C# you don't write `getXXX` methods, additionally C# recommends using proper casing for method names, not Camel casing like Java.